# insert into date query give me wrong date sql server

Tags: sql-server

when i try this query in the sql server query edit

```
INSERT INTO table ( postdate) Values (07/09/2010 )
```

or

```
INSERT INTO table ( postdate) Values (cast (07/09/2010 as datetime)
```

it insert this `1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM`

so why i'm missing here???

Comment: http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Answer (score 3):

```
        INSERT INTO table ( postdate) Values ('2010-09-07' )
```

Answer (score 2):

`07/09/2010` = 7 divided by 9 divided by 2010 with integer arithmetic

This of course gives zero which is `01 Jan 1900 00:00:00.000`

Use SQL Server "safe" ISO (yyyymmdd) + delimiters

```
INSERT INTO table ( postdate) Values ('20100907')
```